# Magento Forgotpassword not working after update

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, forgot-password

I updated my webshop to 1.9.2.3. When I try to reset my password I do receive the email, but when I click the link to change my password I see a blank page.

I've looked this up on Google and changes `customer_account_resetpassword` to `customer_account_changeforgotten`. I changed it in all my customer.xml files just to be sure and I also cleared the cache, but without success.

I also noticed that the URL in the mail is: https://xxx.xx/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=976&token=b13713eb50b22b5a1320adbe08fdf08e but I get redirected to the page https://xxx.xx/customer/account/changeforgotten/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue that was created due to a recent patch that Magento released. They are now enforcing that forms with POST actions must submit the validation token. If you look at the link below, you will find the solution for this problem.

See - https://magentary.com/kb/reset-password-blank-page-after-supee-6788/

I hope this helps! I just recently had this issue myself.